# Local storage for multiple select2 options and checkboxes without overwriting

Tags: jquery, local-storage, jquery-select2

My brain always turns to mush when it comes to local storage.  I want to assign the selection of multiple checkboxes and select2 dropdown options to local storage.  I've managed to scramble together a nice bit of code for the checkboxes, with no overwriting.  I now need to add the dropdown selections.  But so far all my efforts keep overwriting the checkbox selections and vice versa.  Ideally, I'm looking for a few tweaks to the existing storage code I've got, to include the dropdowns, but don't know if this is possible.  Any help much appreciated.  Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tw3fx8q9/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div id="Country_trREPT_Store">
  <label><input type="checkbox"  id="UN20r"/>Andorra</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"  id="UN40r"/>Austria</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"  id="UN56r" />Belgium</label>
</div>


<div id="myDropdowns">
  <select id="drop_plate" multiple="multiple" style='margin-top: 20px'>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

  <select id="drop_sheet" multiple="multiple" style='margin-top: 20px'>
   <option value="four">four</option>
   <option value="five">five</option>
   <option value="six">six</option>
</select>
</div>
```

.
    $(function() {

```
  var $containers = $('#Country_trREPT_Store');
  var $Sel2Dropdowns = $('#myDropdowns');


// Save INDIVIDUALLY SELECTED checkbox status to local-storage
  $containers.on("change", "input", function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
    var selected = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    selected = '#' + selected.join(',#');
   localStorage.setItem('TradeTab_LocalStorage', selected);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('TradeTab_LocalStorage'));
  });

})
```

Comment: Why not use a different key for the other storage?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but still can't seem to get the storage as a whole to work